# How to dupe-close these questions about The Kingkiller Chronicles

Tags: discussion

We have at least four [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) questions with accepted answers on these books, one with the overall series as the answer, two for *The Name of the Wind*, and one for *The Wise Man's Fear*. They ask about different aspects of the books, but all are fairly good answers. I have a gold badge, so my vote would auto-close it, making me uncomfortable making that call.

- [Story identification: Fantasy novel with a faun named Benji](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/78848/23243)
- [Story Identification: Fantasy, magic system involves holding contradictory thoughts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/83756/23243)
- [Book about a famous wizard before he was famous](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/279044/23243)
- [Assassin/Fantasy Novel with Tree of Blades test](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/279498/23243)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This all seems very straightforward and I'm not at all uncomfortable about swinging the dupe stick here.

- I've edited the title of *the book series* into all four accepted answers
- I've duped them off to [this question and answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/279045/20774) as it seems to be the most highly regarded and also contains the largest amount of relevant info about the book series.
- I've taken the liberty of cleaning up all the links
- I've corrected a bunch of grammar and spelling mistakes and removed a bunch of chatter from the questions
- I've slung upvotes on everything because they're all pretty decently written.

Done.

Comment: I'd wondered why I suddenly had new upvotes on that.